# Count the percentage number of colours in an image

Tags: matlab

I have completed a programming that can count up to 8 colors in images by using the RGB method from 000 up to 111. I need to do some modification to it. So far I declare the number if above 128 will equal to 1 & below 128 will be 0. It will count the 8 colours. How to increase the number of colours count? Here is an example of code for count up to 8 colours:

```
rgbImage = imread('football.jpg');
imshow(rgbImage);
[w,h,d] = size(rgbImage)
redChannel = rgbImage(:,:, 1);
greenChannel = rgbImage(:,:, 2);
blueChannel = rgbImage(:,:, 3);
quantizedImage=zeros(size(rgbImage));
count=zeros(1,8);
for i = 1:w 
    for j = 1:h        
      if redChannel(i,j) > 128,
          aredChannel2 = 1;
      else
          aredChannel2=0;
      end
      quantizedImage(i,j,1)=aredChannel2*255;
      if greenChannel(i,j) > 128,
        agreenChannel2 = 1;
      else
        agreenChannel2=0;
      end
      quantizedImage(i,j,2)=agreenChannel2*255;
      if blueChannel(i,j) > 128,
        ablueChannel2 = 1;
      else
        ablueChannel2=0;
      end
      quantizedImage(i,j,3)=ablueChannel2*255;
      bin=4*aredChannel2+2*agreenChannel2+ablueChannel2+1;
      count(bin)=count(bin)+1;
    end
end
figure, imshow(uint8(quantizedImage));
```

Comment: As the code above count up to 8 colours only. Let say I want to increase the colour count to 64 number of colours.

Comment: @rayryeng  can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) to help you achieve your goal.
First, create a colormap with 64 colors. This colormap is created by dividing each color channel (R,G and B) into 4 bins total 4*4*4 = 64 possible colors.
The range of each color channel is between 0 and 1, therefore the centers of the bins are 0.1250, 0.3750, 0.6250 and 0.8750. Or in a more Matlab-ish language: `(0:.25:.75)+0.125`.
I am using [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to create the cartesian product between all possible bins:

```
[C{1:3}] = meshgrid( (0:.25:.75)+0.125 );
cmp = [C{1}(:) C{2}(:) C{3}(:)];
```

Once you have the 64-colors colormap you can quantize the image

```
qImg = rgb2ind( rgbImage, cmp, 'nodither');
```

That's it!

Here's your output

```
figure;imagesc(qImg);colormap(cmp);
```

[image]

If you want to count the number of pixels in each of the 64 bins, you can simply use [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html)

```
count = hist( double(qImg(:)), 64 );
```

Comment: well i got error for this code:
count = hist( qImg(:), 64 );

Comment: mind if I ask you how you create a colormap for 64 colours? I need to know if I want to increase more colours.

Comment: @RabaniAhmadTasman the first two lines of code in the answer creates the colormap `cmp` with 64 colors.

Comment: yes, I get the first two line of code. But I just want to know how you came out with it. Sorry for asking too many question.

Comment: @RabaniAhmadTasman please see my edit. you should try and "play" with the code a little to understand it better.

Comment: hello i use other image to test but somehow the result produce smaller image. how can i maintain the result image same as the original image?

Comment: AFAIK rgb2ind does not change the size of the image.