# Count the percentage number of colours in an image by using HSV method

Tags: matlab, hsv

I have completed a programming that can count up to 64 colors in images by using the RGB method. However, I dont see any link that I can refer to use HSV method. Anybody can give a start up idea on how I'm gonna do this?

Comment: what method is the "RGB method" exactly? and what method is the HSV method? i have the feeling this is just a manner of speaking about different encodings of color in reading the image and not  specific algorithms..

Comment: @NikosM. I guess he is mentioning about the previous question he asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763476/count-the-percentage-number-of-colours-in-an-image

Comment: Refer [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064205/2111163). @gnovice has done that for 360 colors.

Comment: @SanthanSalai thank you very much. yeah the RGB method is from my previous question. Im refering  gnovice question right now to do the HSV method of identifying colors. Thank you very much :)